# Delete part of the string to the character encountered javascript

Tags: javascript

I would need to write a js function that would do this to me:

```
export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'app/LoginPage/LOGIN_REQUEST';
```

Normally it will be:

```
console.log(LOGIN_REQUEST); // app/LoginPage/LOGIN_REQUEST
```

And I would need:

```
app/LoginPage/LOGIN
```

I would like to cut the string to the first one I encountered `_`. How to do it using js?

Answer (score 1):

`LOGIN_REQUEST.split('_')[0]`

Splits LOGIN_REQUEST into an array of strings, divided by `_`, and returns the first element of the Array. So, everything up to the first `_`.

More fully:

```
const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'app/LoginPage/LOGIN_REQUEST';

console.log(LOGIN_REQUEST.split(`_`)) // ['app/LoginPage/LOGIN', 'REQUEST']

console.log(LOGIN_REQUEST.split(`_`)[0]) // 'app/LoginPage/LOGIN'
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the index of this character using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method, and then take the substring before its first occurrence using the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method as follows:

```js
let LOGIN_REQUEST = 'app/LoginPage/LOGIN_REQUEST';
let i = LOGIN_REQUEST.indexOf('_');
let str = (i==-1) ? LOGIN_REQUEST : LOGIN_REQUEST.substring(0,i);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can use the `split` function.

```
var data = "app/LoginPage/LOGIN_REQUEST".split("_");
console.log(data[0]); // app/LoginPage/LOGIN
```